# How to loop over taints on an EksNodeGroup with Terraform CDK?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform-cdk

I have an EksNodeGroup with the following taints:

```js
    const ssdEksNodeGroupPublicLargeSubnet = new aws.eks.EksNodeGroup(
      this,
      "ssdEksNodeGroupPublicLargeSubnet",
      {
        // ... other stuff...
        
        taint: [
          {
            key: "app",
            value: "strick",
            effect: "NO_SCHEDULE",
          },
        ],
      }
    );
```

Elsewhere in my code, I'm trying to iterate over my nodeGroup taints to dynamically create kubernetes pod tolerations.

```js
      const nodeGrouop = ssdEksNodeGroupPublicLargeSubnet
      const tolerations: k8s.DeploymentSpecTemplateSpecToleration[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < Fn.lengthOf(nodeGroup.taint); i++) {
        const taint = nodeGroup.taint.get(i);
        tolerations.push({
          key: taint.key,
          value: taint.value,
          effect: taint.effect,
          operator: "Equal"
        });
      }
      console.log("##################", tolerations)
```

However, when I try to run this, I see the log statement prints an empty array and when my pod/deployment is created it is created with no tolerations.

Here's full declaration of my kubernetes deployment

```js
      const pausePodDeployment = new k8s.Deployment(
        this,
        pausePodDeploymentName,
        {
          metadata: {
            name: pausePodDeploymentName,
            namespace: namespace.metadata.name,
          },
          spec: {
            replicas: "1",
            selector: {
              matchLabels: {
                app: pausePodDeploymentName,
              },
            },
            template: {
              metadata: {
                labels: {
                  app: pausePodDeploymentName,
                },
              },
              spec: {
                priorityClassName: priorityClass.metadata.name,
                terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0,
                container: [
                  {
                    name: "reserve-resources",
                    image: "k8s.gcr.io/pause",
                    resources: {
                      requests: {
                        cpu: "1",
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
                toleration: tolerations,
                nodeSelector: {
                  ...nodeGroupLabels,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        }
      );
```

and here's the full output from CDK (note that there aren't any tolerations):

```
# kubernetes_deployment.overprovisioner_strick-overprovisioner-pause-pods_B5F26972 (overprovisioner/strick-overprovisioner-pause-pods) will be created
                     + resource "kubernetes_deployment" "overprovisioner_strick-overprovisioner-pause-pods_B5F26972" {
                         + id               = (known after apply)
                         + wait_for_rollout = true

                         + metadata {
                             + generation       = (known after apply)
                             + name             = "strick-overprovisioner-pause-pods"
                             + namespace        = "overprovisioner"
                             + resource_version = (known after apply)
                             + uid              = (known after apply)
                           }

                         + spec {
                             + min_ready_seconds         = 0
                             + paused                    = false
                             + progress_deadline_seconds = 600
                             + replicas                  = "1"
                             + revision_history_limit    = 10

                             + selector {
                                 + match_labels = {
                                     + "app" = "strick-overprovisioner-pause-pods"
                                   }
                               }

                             + strategy {
                                 + type = (known after apply)

                                 + rolling_update {
                                     + max_surge       = (known after apply)
                                     + max_unavailable = (known after apply)
                                   }
                               }

                             + template {
                                 + metadata {
                                     + generation       = (known after apply)
                                     + labels           = {
                                         + "app" = "strick-overprovisioner-pause-pods"
                                       }
                                     + name             = (known after apply)
                                     + resource_version = (known after apply)
                                     + uid              = (known after apply)
                                   }

                                 + spec {
                                     + automount_service_account_token  = true
                                     + dns_policy                       = "ClusterFirst"
                                     + enable_service_links             = true
                                     + host_ipc                         = false
                                     + host_network                     = false
                                     + host_pid                         = false
                                     + hostname                         = (known after apply)
                                     + node_name                        = (known after apply)
                                     + node_selector                    = {
                                         + "diskType" = "ssd"
                                       }
                                     + priority_class_name              = "overprovisioner"
                                     + restart_policy                   = "Always"
                                     + service_account_name             = (known after apply)
                                     + share_process_namespace          = false
                                     + termination_grace_period_seconds = 0

                                     + container {
                                         + image                      = "k8s.gcr.io/pause"
                                         + image_pull_policy          = (known after apply)
                                         + name                       = "reserve-resources"
                                         + stdin                      = false
                                         + stdin_once                 = false
                                         + termination_message_path   = "/dev/termination-log"
                                         + termination_message_policy = (known after apply)
                                         + tty                        = false

                                         + resources {
                                             + limits   = (known after apply)
                                             + requests = {
                                                 + "cpu" = "1"
                                               }
                                           }
                                       }

                                     + image_pull_secrets {
                                         + name = (known after apply)
                                       }

                                     + readiness_gate {
                                         + condition_type = (known after apply)
                                       }

                                     + volume {
                                         + name = (known after apply)

                                         + aws_elastic_block_store {
                                             + fs_type   = (known after apply)
                                             + partition = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only = (known after apply)
                                             + volume_id = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + azure_disk {
                                             + caching_mode  = (known after apply)
                                             + data_disk_uri = (known after apply)
                                             + disk_name     = (known after apply)
                                             + fs_type       = (known after apply)
                                             + kind          = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only     = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + azure_file {
                                             + read_only        = (known after apply)
                                             + secret_name      = (known after apply)
                                             + secret_namespace = (known after apply)
                                             + share_name       = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + ceph_fs {
                                             + monitors    = (known after apply)
                                             + path        = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only   = (known after apply)
                                             + secret_file = (known after apply)
                                             + user        = (known after apply)

                                             + secret_ref {
                                                 + name      = (known after apply)
                                                 + namespace = (known after apply)
                                               }
                                           }

                                         + cinder {
                                             + fs_type   = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only = (known after apply)
                                             + volume_id = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + config_map {
                                             + default_mode = (known after apply)
                                             + name         = (known after apply)
                                             + optional     = (known after apply)

                                             + items {
                                                 + key  = (known after apply)
                                                 + mode = (known after apply)
                                                 + path = (known after apply)
                                               }
                                           }

                                         + csi {
                                             + driver            = (known after apply)
                                             + fs_type           = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only         = (known after apply)
                                             + volume_attributes = (known after apply)

                                             + node_publish_secret_ref {
                                                 + name = (known after apply)
                                               }
                                           }

                                         + downward_api {
                                             + default_mode = (known after apply)

                                             + items {
                                                 + mode = (known after apply)
                                                 + path = (known after apply)

                                                 + field_ref {
                                                     + api_version = (known after apply)
                                                     + field_path  = (known after apply)
                                                   }

                                                 + resource_field_ref {
                                                     + container_name = (known after apply)
                                                     + divisor        = (known after apply)
                                                     + resource       = (known after apply)
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }

                                         + empty_dir {
                                             + medium     = (known after apply)
                                             + size_limit = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + fc {
                                             + fs_type      = (known after apply)
                                             + lun          = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only    = (known after apply)
                                             + target_ww_ns = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + flex_volume {
                                             + driver    = (known after apply)
                                             + fs_type   = (known after apply)
                                             + options   = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only = (known after apply)

                                             + secret_ref {
                                                 + name      = (known after apply)
                                                 + namespace = (known after apply)
                                               }
                                           }

                                         + flocker {
                                             + dataset_name = (known after apply)
                                             + dataset_uuid = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + gce_persistent_disk {
                                             + fs_type   = (known after apply)
                                             + partition = (known after apply)
                                             + pd_name   = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + git_repo {
                                             + directory  = (known after apply)
                                             + repository = (known after apply)
                                             + revision   = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + glusterfs {
                                             + endpoints_name = (known after apply)
                                             + path           = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only      = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + host_path {
                                             + path = (known after apply)
                                             + type = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + iscsi {
                                             + fs_type         = (known after apply)
                                             + iqn             = (known after apply)
                                             + iscsi_interface = (known after apply)
                                             + lun             = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only       = (known after apply)
                                             + target_portal   = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + local {
                                             + path = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + nfs {
                                             + path      = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only = (known after apply)
                                             + server    = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + persistent_volume_claim {
                                             + claim_name = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only  = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + photon_persistent_disk {
                                             + fs_type = (known after apply)
                                             + pd_id   = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + projected {
                                             + default_mode = (known after apply)

                                             + sources {
                                                 + config_map {
                                                     + name     = (known after apply)
                                                     + optional = (known after apply)

                                                     + items {
                                                         + key  = (known after apply)
                                                         + mode = (known after apply)
                                                         + path = (known after apply)
                                                       }
                                                   }

                                                 + downward_api {
                                                     + items {
                                                         + mode = (known after apply)
                                                         + path = (known after apply)

                                                         + field_ref {
                                                             + api_version = (known after apply)
                                                             + field_path  = (known after apply)
                                                           }

                                                         + resource_field_ref {
                                                             + container_name = (known after apply)
                                                             + divisor        = (known after apply)
                                                             + resource       = (known after apply)
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                   }

                                                 + secret {
                                                     + name     = (known after apply)
                                                     + optional = (known after apply)

                                                     + items {
                                                         + key  = (known after apply)
                                                         + mode = (known after apply)
                                                         + path = (known after apply)
                                                       }
                                                   }

                                                 + service_account_token {
                                                     + audience           = (known after apply)
                                                     + expiration_seconds = (known after apply)
                                                     + path               = (known after apply)
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }

                                         + quobyte {
                                             + group     = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only = (known after apply)
                                             + registry  = (known after apply)
                                             + user      = (known after apply)
                                             + volume    = (known after apply)
                                           }

                                         + rbd {
                                             + ceph_monitors = (known after apply)
                                             + fs_type       = (known after apply)
                                             + keyring       = (known after apply)
                                             + rados_user    = (known after apply)
                                             + rbd_image     = (known after apply)
                                             + rbd_pool      = (known after apply)
                                             + read_only     = (known after apply)

                                             + secret_ref {
                                                 + name      = (known after apply)
                                                 + namespace = (known after apply)
                                               }
                                           }

                                         + secret {
                                             + default_mode = (known after apply)
                                             + optional     = (known after apply)
                                             + secret_name  = (known after apply)

                                             + items {
                                                 + key  = (known after apply)
                                                 + mode = (known after apply)
                                                 + path = (known after apply)
                                               }
                                           }

                                         + vsphere_volume {
                                             + fs_type     = (known after apply)
                                             + volume_path = (known after apply)
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
                               }
                           }
```

How can I dynamically iterate over the taints of a nodegroup to construct the correct pod tolerations for that node group?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the [Token System](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/tokens) powering CDKTF. Instead of real run-time values accessing `ssdEksNodeGroupPublicLargeSubnet.taint` gives you a token that is a reference to the taints. This reference is later used by Terraform for e.g. ordering the deployments of the individual resources.

If your input is static you can use the input directly by accessing `ssdEksNodeGroupPublicLargeSubnet.taintInput`.

If you want to loop over the taints on the terraform side instead of during synthetisation you can use [dynamic blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/iterators#using-iterators-for-list-attributes), e.g.

```
const iterator = TerraformIterator.fromList(ssdEksNodeGroupPublicLargeSubnet.taint);
const tolerations = iterator.dynamic({
  key: cdktf.propertyAccess(iterator.value, "key"),
  value: cdktf.propertyAccess(iterator.value, "value"),
  effect: cdktf.propertyAccess(iterator.value, "effect"),
  operator: "Equal"
})
```